# Create a Fraction array

Tags: objective-c, c

I have to Create a dynamic array capable of holding 2*n Fractions.
 If the dynamic array cannot be allocated, prints a message and calls exit(1).
 It next fills the array with reduced random Fractions whose numerator
 is between 1 and 20, inclusive; and whose initial denominator
 is between 2 and 20, inclusive.

I ready did the function that is going to create the fraction and reduced it. this is what I got. When I compiled and run this program it crashes I cant find out why. If I put 1 instead of 10 in the test.c It doesn't crash but it gives me a crazy fraction. If I put 7,8,or 11 in the test.c it will crash. I would appreciate if someone can help me.

FractionSumTester.c

```
Fraction randomFraction(int minNum, int minDenom, int max)
{
   Fraction l;
   Fraction m;
   Fraction f;

   l.numerator = randomInt(minNum, max);
   l.denominator = randomInt(minDenom, max);

   m = reduceFraction(l);

 while (m.denominator <= 1)
   {
        l.numerator = randomInt(minNum, max);
    l.denominator = randomInt(minDenom, max);
    m = reduceFraction(l);
   }
   return m;


}


Fraction *createFractionArray(int n)
{
   Fraction *p;
   int i;


   p = malloc(n * sizeof(Fraction));

   if (p == NULL)
   {
     printf("error");
     exit(1);
   }

   for(i=0; i < 2*n ; i++)
   {

      p[i] = randomFraction(1,2,20);
      printf("%d/%d\n", p[i].numerator, p[i].denominator);


   }

   return p;


}
```

this is the what I am using to test this two functions.

test.c

```
#include "Fraction.h"
#include "FractionSumTester.h"
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{

      createFractionArray(10);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should note that on most linux systems, malloc will always succeed because memory overcommit (http://opsmonkey.blogspot.com/2007/01/linux-memory-overcommit.html) will give you the requested memory, but won't actually allocate it until you try to use it. I'm sure this is for a class so you don't have to worry about this, but it's good to keep in mind as there can be all sorts of bugs introduced because of this

Answer (score 1):

In your createFractionArray() function, you malloc() space for n items.  Then, in the for loop, you write 2*n items into that space... which overruns your buffer and causes the crash.

Comment: So, instead of only putting n. Should I put p=malloc((2*n)* sizeof(Fraction))

Comment: Thank you so much. It work I tried everything but I never thought about that. Thank you again.

Comment: If you want createFractionArray() to create 2*n fractions, your change is correct.  It makes more sense to me to keep your malloc() the same and change your for loop to `for (i=0; i<n; i++)`.  That way, by calling createFractionArray(), you ask for (say) 10 fractions, and that's how many you get.